I can't install Ubuntu 24.04
firstly I would like to apologize because I am new at Linux and these installations. I downloaded the latest Ubuntu from official website. I plugged my usb drive and got ready for installation. However when I open it, installation shuts down after a while. I try to open it again and it just says Preparing Ubuntu... then shuts down again. I can move the mouse around but can't click anything, and after a while can't move the mouse neither. Sometimes it either shows error messages or just freezes. What should I do?

Try starting a Live Ubuntu session and report if it works or gives any errors.

Live Ubuntu session => Boot the USB and use Try Ubuntu-mode. If that runs without any issues, try launching the installation from there.

"installation shuts down" Edit your question to clearly explain what you experience. I cannot tell from that phrase if the system is powering off, or if the installer is aborting, or if the installer is claiming success, or something else. Help us to help you.

Well, I had a similar problem. The installation process proceeded till the end and ended in an error. I just reinstalled ubuntu iso again and it worked. And regarding the mouse problem, why not just try keyboard.

I had a similar problem. With 'Startup Disk Creator' I couldn't get even past the first menu before it hung up. With 'UnetBootin' I got to the 'Try Ubuntu' menu and then nothing. So I installed Balena Etcher to burn the ISO and it worked perfectly and had zero issues. https://etcher.balena.io/ ..I recommend a 16gb USB drive. The system-file is about 7gb on the drive and the install will likely fail with an 8gb USB.. I hope this helps.
